# Validation gets removed after calling event.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Validation gets removed  from SSN textbox after calling **event.preventDefault();** in $("form").submit(function (event)

Validation gets fired and than removed

```
    function CheckSSN() {

        var sender = $("#SSN");
        var value = $(sender).val();
        var errorSpan = $(sender).siblings("span[data-valmsg-for='SSN']");
        var message = "SSN is required.";
        var validAliasPatt = /^[0-9]{9}$/;
        if (!value || value == "" || value == null) {

            enableValidationUI(sender, errorSpan, message);
            return false;
        }
        else if (!validAliasPatt.test(value)) {
            message = "SSN should be a 9 digit number.";
            enableValidationUI(sender, errorSpan, message);
            return false;
        }
        else {
            disableValidationUI(sender, errorSpan);
            return true;
        }
    }
----------

    ("form").submit(function (event) {

        var submit = true;        

        if (!CheckSSN()) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var submit = false;
        }

        if (submit) {
            $("form").submit();
        }
        else {
            event.preventDefault();
            return;
        }

    });
```

Comment: What kind of validation ? And where `event.preventDefault()` is called ?

Comment: i am calling this in form submit  -  $("form").submit(function (event) { }

Comment: You can remove all event.preventDefault(); entries from validation methods and call based on submit value at the end of method.

Comment: You have an element `"span[data-valmsg-for='SSN']"` which suggest your using `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` so why are you not using unobtrusive client side validation?

Comment: no i have to make validation database driven it is just from setting error message i am not using unobtrusive client side validation

Comment: You have a method `("form").submit()` which then calls `("form").submit` which would create an endless loop. Hard to understand what your trying to do with this.

Comment: you are right Stephen the issue was with ('from').submit changing it to buttom.click method fixed it .

Comment: And what do you mean _i have to make validation database driven_ What you have shown is validation on the client! With one simple `RegularExpressionAttribute` applied to your `SSN` property you can delete all this code and get client side and server side validation out of the box.

Comment: m sory not for ssn but for other fields you can see in the code. This issue i was facing that i can't make data annotation work as i wanted to enable and disable validation depending on entry in database. Ended up writing all javascript validation  .

Comment: You have 15 odd lines of code that then has to be repeated on the server for just one property (`SSN`) and you have shown that you have at least another 15 properties where you must be doing similar things. Why on earth would you do that instead of using all the inbuilt validation features of MVC (and and just a few lines of code)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92951/discussion-between-sachin-prasad-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with using ("form").submit(function (event) which ended up creating endless loop. After changing to ('button').click fixed this issue.